# how to get the button's element id when clicked and use it in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, while-loop

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

    $(".dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 400
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 400
    }
    });

    $( ".opener" ).on ('click',MyJQFunction);
});
function MyJQFunction() {
    $(".dialog").dialog( "open" );
}
</script>

 <?php

 $x = 0;
 while($x < 5){
 $x = $x+1;

 $did1 = 'dialog'.$x;
 $did2 = 'opener'.$x;
 ?>

 <div class = "dialog" id= <?php echo $did1; ?>  title=<?php echo $did1; ?>>
 <p> <?php echo $did1; ?> </p>
 </div>

 <button class= "opener" > <?php echo $did2; ?> Contact</button>

 <?php
 }//end of while loop
 ?>
```

I am basically creating a table using the while loop. 
For each button and `<p>` I am assigning specific id. 
Now, I want to grab this id and when the button is clicked, 
show that specific `<p>`.

However, when I click one button, all buttons come up at the same time.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the dialog that is preceding the button, you can always refer to the button inside its handler with `this` keyword and then use `prev` to grab the dialog div. You dont necessarily need the id atleast with the structure you have posted.

Try this way:

```
function MyJQFunction() {
    $(this).prev(".dialog").dialog( "open" );
    //to get the id of the dialog
     //$(this).prev(".dialog")[0].id;
}
```

**Update**

This won't work since jquery dialog gets created prior to the button click and they are placed in the bottom of the body. So change you php code for button generation to:

i.e Attach a `data-target` attribute to target the dialog with particular id.

```
<button class= "opener" data-target="#<?php echo $did1; ?>"> <?php echo $did2; ?> Contact</button>
```

and change your script to:

```
function MyJQFunction() {
    $($(this).data('target')).dialog( "open" );
}
```

Full Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

    $(".dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 400
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 400
    }
    });

    $( ".opener" ).on ('click',MyJQFunction);
});
function MyJQFunction() {
    $($(this).data('target')).dialog( "open" );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <?php

 $x = 0;
 while($x < 5){
 $x = $x+1;

 $did1 = 'dialog'.$x;
 $did2 = 'opener'.$x;
 ?>

 <div class = "dialog" id= <?php echo $did1; ?>  title=<?php echo $did1; ?>>
 <p> <?php echo $did1; ?> </p>
 </div>

 <button class= "opener" data-target="#<?php echo $did1; ?>"> <?php echo $did2; ?> Contact</button>

 <?php
 }//end of while loop
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason, This does not seem to solve my problem. Would it be possible to send you my code for you to look over? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @user2840665 Please post your code in the question itself, if not me somebody else will definitely help you.

Comment: @user2840665 how may of these dialogues and respective buttons you have?

Comment: I have a lot. Sorry, im new to jquery so I am not too good with this. the While loop is creating a lot of them

Comment: @user2840665 can you show rendered html... With what you posted doesn't seem like right structure. Also do you see any errors in the conosle, place some `debugger` statements in your code and inspect if it is going inside the handler at all, and if so is it fetching the div element etc..

Comment: Hello. I have simplified the code and editted my post. Now, when you just copy everything from my code and paste it in your text editor, it should run fine by itself. Again, thank you so much for helping me out here.

Comment: No, it is not. If i click one button, all of <p> comes up. Sorry for the confusion. I tried to post an img, but stackoverflow does not let me because I have low reputation. But now when you copy and paste my code in an empty text editor and run it, you can see the rendered html.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a data attribute like so

```
<button class= "opener" data-dialog="<?php echo $did2; ?>"><?php echo $did2; ?> Contact</button>

function MyJQFunction() {
    var dialog = $(this).attr('data-dialog');
    $(dialog).dialog("open");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID you can use .attr('id')  or .attr('class') if you want to get the class of the object.

Example :

```
<button id='12345'>12345</button>


$('button').on('click',function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);
});
```